# Using multiple data items in foreach loop

Tags: c#, variables, foreach, text-files

I have the data items as:

```
Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> tPapers = eAuthor.GetPapersBetweenYears(year, year + 1);  
List<int> tCoAuthors = eAuthor.GetCoAuthorsBetweenYears(year, year + 1);  
List<int> tVenues = eAuthor.GetVenuesBetweenYears(year, year + 1);
```

I have to write all these data items i.e. `tPapers`, `tCoAuthors` and `tVenues` into the text file. I tried as:

```
foreach (var kvpaper in tPapers)
{
   // Key is Paper_ID, Item1 is Paper_Category, Item2 is Year
   twObjClus.WriteLine("PaperID: {0}, PaperCategory: {1}, Year: {2}",  
                       kvpaper.Key, kvpaper.Value.Item1, kvpaper.Value.Item2);
}
```

Whereas I want to have output written in this form as:

> Paper_ID: 1, Paper_Category: 3, CoAutohr_ID: 34, Venue_ID: 23, Year:
>   2005

How can I use all these data items in a single `foreach()` loop or separate loops needed for each of data items?

Comment: are `Dictionary` and the 2 `List` of the same length?

Comment: No these are not of the same length, it is likely to repeat the other data item's value if one falls short of length for specific ID's. For example, a single Paper can have single Venue but it may comprise number of CoAuthors so that Paper_ID should get repeat with corresponding CoAuthors

Comment: it would be interesting to know then how you would reference between the 3. How do you determine that exactly those `CoAuthors`  wrote on exactly this `PaperID` ?

Comment: That what I wanna to link it with

Comment: Both lists contain ID's of two different entities according to a given time-range(two years). But the ID does not know to which year it belonged since it's a plain `int`. How do you want to determine the year? You should return complex types like `IEnumerable<Book>` which contains all informations like `Autor`, `CoAuthor(s)`, `PublishDate` etc

Comment: As all of three data items are between same time-range

Comment: @Taufel: but you want to output the year and you don't know it anymore after you have used `GetCoAuthorsBetweenYears` and `GetVenuesBetweenYears`. Only the dictionary knows the year because the tuple's `Item2` contains it.

Comment: Can I merge `tCoAuthors` and `tVenues` in the `Tuple` above in `Dictionary`?

Comment: Why don't you create a custom class with all the data about the book, as @TimSchmelter suggested above. It's chaotic to have three data types in different sources when you can merge them in one custom class.

Comment: @D.Petrov The only reason is that I only have `CoAuthors` occurrences repetitively in the data whereas rest is as each `Paper` will have single `Venue` and single `Year`

Comment: Heck is this that can't I combine more than one variable in `foreach()` loop that automatically repeats the required values

Comment: What is `eAuthor`? Is it a `db` table? A list?. Are you limited to only using methods `GetPapersBetweenYears`, `GetCoAuthorsBetweenYears` etc.? Or can you write your own queries? Your problem is tivially solved if you could select in one single query all necessary fields:  `Paper_Id`, `Paper_Category`, `CoAuthor_Id` and `Venue`.

Comment: @InBetween `eAuthor` is a list of authors whereas I've defined these methods in class `Author` to access specific valued attributes of the class. I've used a single query to extract all the data from database then assigned it to the object `eAuthor` as a list but the heck is I've to access specific valued attributes of class `Author` each time in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have the tools to solve your problem as it stands right now. Your methods `GetCoAuthorsBetweenYears` and `GetVenuesBetweenYears` simply do not return the necessary information.

Why? Well, how do you relate any given record returned by `GetCoAuthorsBetweenYears` to a `Paper_Id`? This method simply returns all `CoAuthors` stored in `eAuthors`. What you need is a method with one of the following signatures:

```
 List<Tuple<int, int>> GetDocumentsAndCoAuthorsBetweenYears(int lower, int upper) //Tuple.Value1 stores Paper_Id and Tuple.Value2 stores CoAuthor_ID.

 List<int> GetCoAuthorsByDocumentBetweenYears(int documentId, int lower, int upper)
```

Now, in both cases you can relate `CoAuthor_ID` information with `Paper_ID`s. Same with venues.

Ok, but if you can modify these methods, then why are we doing this to begin with? What prevents you from implementing the following one:

```
IEnumerable<PaperInfo> GetPaperInfoBetweenYears(int lower, int upper);
```

Where `PaperInfo` would be:

```
class PaperInfo
{
    public int Paper_ID { get; set; }
    public int CoAuthor_ID { get; set; }
    public int Paper_Category { get; set; }
    public int Venue_ID { get; set; }
}
```

And now you'd simply print your `IEnumerable<PaperInfo>`:

```
var papers = GetAllPaperInfoBetweenYears(year, year + 1);
var printedInfo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                             papers.Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", p.Paper_ID, p.Paper_Category, p.CoAuthor_ID, p.Venue_ID));
```

*UPDATE* Per your comments, I've put together a small example:

```
 public class Author
 {
     public int Paper_ID { get; set; }
     public int CoAuthor_ID { get; set; }
     public int Venue_ID { get; set; }
     public int Paper_Category { get; set; }
     public int Year { get; }
     public int Publisher_ID { get; }
     //etc.
 }

 //bring all info from database   
 IEnumerable<Author> eAuthors = GetAllInfoFromDB();

 //Now filter and project what you need
 public static IEnumerable<PaperInfo> GetGetPaperInfoBetweenYears(this List<Author> eAuthors, int lower, int upper)
 {
     return from eAuthor in eAuthors
            where (eAuthor.Year >= lower && eAuthor.Year < upper)
            select new PaperInfo() { Paper_ID = eAuthor.Paper_ID, CoAuthor_ID = eAuthor.CoAuthor_ID, Paper_Category = eAuthor.Paper_Category, Venue_ID = eAuthor.Venue_ID };
 }
```

Of course you could even do without `PaperInfo` and simply filter by year and project the whole information stored in `eAuthorInfo`:

```
public static IEnumerable<PaperInfo> GetGetPaperInfoBetweenYears(this List<Author> eAuthors, int lower, int upper)
 {
     return from eAuthor in eAuthors
            where (eAuthor.Year >= lower && eAuthor.Year < upper)
            select eAuthor;
 }
```

And, same as before, simply print out the info you need:

```
var printedInfo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                             papers.Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", p.Paper_ID, p.Paper_Category, p.CoAuthor_ID, p.Venue_ID)); //no year, publisher, etc. info
```

This is the way I'd do it, projections are really useful but are a pain when you have a lot of them and you can't use anonymous types; it makes you have to implement a type for each projection.

Comment: As you suggested `IEnumerable<PaperInfo>`, the attribute `Year` is missing here, and we may have more than 1 `CoAuthor_ID`s for a single `Paper_ID`, how will we handle it in `PaperInfo`

Comment: @Taufel You dont. That should be handled already in your `eAuthor` list. How is it handled there? If one `Paper_ID` has more than one `CoAuthor_ID` then how is it stored in `eAuhtor`? I'm guessing you'll have two records, one for each coauthor and all other information duplicated. Well then, the job is already done, just print it out duplicated. About the missing year, that is the whole point, you project what you need. Do not conflate the generic type of the `eAuthor` list with `PaperInfo`. Those need to be different, the latter defining the projection you need.

Comment: Still not getting right about `Year` and repeated `CoAuthor_ID`s. Where are these while creating `new PaperInfo()`?

Comment: @Taufel You project *what you need*. You need `Year`? Add that to the projection, same way you add `Paper_ID`, `Venue_ID`, etc. About repeated CoAuthor_ID's, again, that is already solved in `eAuthor`. How are repeated `CoAuthor_ID`s stored in `eAuthor`?

Comment: All is what I've to add List of CoAuthor_IDs in PaperInfo to project it, yeah I got it